# tsung-recorder still running after "tsung-recorder stop"

Tags: testing, automated-tests, benchmarking, tsung

I set up a Tsung configuration on my mac and tried to record a test on the web site I'm developing.

I ran : "tsung-recorder start"
and set the proxy for tsung in firefox localhost:8090.
Then I navigated a bit on the running web site.
I checked the file :

> /tmp/tsung_recorder.pid

which contained the right pid.

Everything was fine until I tried to stop tsung-recorder with "tsung-recorder stop".

> $tsung-recorder stop
>
> $"tsung recorder is not running on my-mac"
>
> [OK]

The problem here is that the recorder is still running in background and that the xml generated is not completed.
All the http request I have done during the recording were recorded in the xml file, so I know everything worked fine during the recording.

I want to know how can I get a correct Tsung testing file with this issue.
Do I have to complete the remaining tag myself ?

Of course resolved the issue about this non-stopping process would be better.
But I don't have any clue on why this is happening.

Tsung version 1.3.1
erlang : otp_src_R13B02-1

ps: please excuse my poor english, everything might not be perfect. I just expect it to be good and clear enough to be understand.

---

Answer (score 1):

I want to know how can I get a correct Tsung testing file with this issue. Do I have to complete the remaining tag myself ?

yes, to the recored session file you'll need to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/usr/share/tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd">
<tsung loglevel="notice" version="1.0">

<load duration="20" unit="minute">
<arrivalphase phase="1" duration="8" unit="minute">
<users interarrival="2" unit="second"></users>
</arrivalphase>
</load>

<options>
<option type="ts_http" name="user_agent">
<user_agent probability="80">Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.7.8)  Gecko/20050513 Galeon/1.3.21</user_agent>
<user_agent probability="20">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; fr-FR; rv:1.7.8) Gecko/20050511 Firefox/1.0.4</user_agent>
</option>
</options>

<sessions>
<session type="ts_http" name="rec20120410-17:49:340" probability="100">
```

ending in

```
</sessions>
```

if you have multiple sessions combined probability need to be == 100